# YAML: How are hierarchical YAML files flattened in Symfony?

Tags: configuration, symfony1, yaml

I have a YAML file with following structure.

```
level1:
  contact:
    website: www.prasadgupte.com
```

I am using `sfYaml::load($file_path)` to load the file as an array. I would like to flatten the array so as to be able to get the key `get('level1_contact_website')` that will return `www.prasadgupte.com`

I went through several code files in Symfony, but could not nail down the file that does this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative:**
if this syntax seems OK, `get('level1[contact][website]')` then use

`sfToolkit::getArrayValueForPath($yaml_array, 'level1[contact][website]');`